# How to impliment the TableDecorator?

Tags: java, displaytag

How to impliment the TableDecorator in my project.Can anyone provide me the steps or code for that.

Comment: Refer to BalusC's excellent [GoF Design Patterns answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns/2707195#2707195) for usage of the Decorator pattern in the Java Library

Comment: Changing topic and content **after** receiving answers is not very nice - note, that my answer is valid for the *original* version of this question...

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience,previously topic is mistakenly written by

Answer (score 2):

"Decorator" is not a class but a design pattern. You'll find a lot of implementations of this pattern in the `java.io` package (look at the streams, for example)

A prominent example, that explains a lot, is the `BufferedInputStream`. This class *decorates* any `InputStream` by adding some buffering.

---

Simple example:

```
 public interface GreetProvider { public String greet(); }

 public class HelloProvider implements GreetProvider { 
    public String greet() {
      return "Hello";
    }
 }

 public class ByeProvider implements GreetProvider { 
    public String greet() {
      return "Good Bye";
    }
 }

 public class SmilyDecorator implements GreetProvider {
    private GreetProvider provider;
    public SmilyDecorator(GreetProvider provider) {this.provider = provider;}

    public String greet() {
      return provider.greet() + " :-)";
    }
 }

 // somwhere in some method

 GreetProvider hello = new HelloProvider();
 GreetProvider bye = new ByeProvider();
 GreetProvider helloAndSmiley = new SmileyDecorator(hello);
 GreetProvider helloAndTwoSmileys = new SmileyDecorator(helloAndSmiley);

 System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n", 
       hello.greet(), bye.greet(),
       helloAndSmiley.greet(), helloAndTwoSmileys.greet());
```

Comment: Changing topic and content after receiving answers is not very nice - note, that my answer is valid for the original version of this question...

Answer (score 1):

Following classes uses decorator pattern:

- All subclasses of `java.io.InputStream, OutputStream, Reader and Writer` have a constructor taking an instance of same type.
- Almost all implementations of `java.util.List`, Set and Map have a constructor taking an instance of same type.
- `java.util.Collections`, the `checkedXXX(), synchronizedXXX() and unmodifiableXXX()` methods.
- `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper and HttpServletResponseWrapper`

Answer (score 0):

OK, apparently we are talking about this [`TableDecorator`](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/displaytag/apidocs/org/displaytag/decorator/TableDecorator.html) class.

Although it is abstract, it has no abstract methods, so I guess the `abstract` modifier is just to stop you from instantiating the super class, use one of the subclasses instead:

> Direct Known Subclasses:
>   [`MultilevelTotalTableDecorator`](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/displaytag/apidocs/org/displaytag/decorator/MultilevelTotalTableDecorator.html),
>   [`TotalTableDecorator`](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/displaytag/apidocs/org/displaytag/decorator/TotalTableDecorator.html)

(I don't think you are meant to implement your own `TableDecorator` class)